# jQuery UI Tooltip won't disappear after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, tooltip

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

I'm using some basic JS to have tooltips enabled on hover. However, if I click the icon with the tooltip, it will remain there until I click something else. How would I change my code above to do this ?

Comment: What else do you want the tooltip to do?

Comment: I just want it to appear on hover and to disappear otherwise.

Comment: if it is jQuery UI tooltip, you'd better to mention it in your question title and tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the jQuery `hover()` method, which has enter and exit handlers: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

You can call `open()` and `close()` on the tooltip on enter and exit respectively:
http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-open

http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-close